# Netlify cannot find build command

Tags: build, gatsby, netlify

I am trying to deploy my first gatsby site, with a blog but it keeps failing. Ive updated all my dependancies but now I cant figure out what exactly is the issue. I tried changing the build settinfs but not 100% if its correct.

github repo: https://github.com/ShuibCodes/Portfolio

```
5:35:20 PM:   Error message
5:35:20 PM:   Command failed with exit code 127: gatsby build
5:35:20 PM: ​
5:35:20 PM:   Error location
5:35:20 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
5:35:20 PM:   gatsby build
5:35:20 PM: ​
5:35:20 PM:   Resolved config
5:35:20 PM:   build:
5:35:20 PM:     command: gatsby build
5:35:20 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
5:35:20 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/Portfolio/Portfolio/gatsby-simplefolio/public
```

Comment: Please add some details. Does it build locally?

Comment: Hey, thank u for the quick reply. your right, the git files were in weird order so I created a new repo. A silly mistake really, thank u!

Comment: check with GitHub repo package.json file make it outer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a weird Git project structure:

```
Portfolio/Portfolio/gatsby-simplefolio
```

[gatsby-simplefolio](https://github.com/ShuibCodes/Portfolio/tree/main/Portfolio/gatsby-simplefolio) should be at the first level of the repository.

Try cleaning up the structure and redo the process.

Netlify's trying to run a `gatsby build` command in a folder that doesn't have any configuration file because it's at the third level.